# Sprite Sheet Animation Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, animation, cocos2d-x, sprite-sheet

I've been working really hard for weeks now trying to get sprite sheet animation to work, and it isn't. I've tried, using this wiki page, http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Sprite_Sheet_Animation, and I've tried to make my own code, and neither have gotten e remotely close to where I want to be and I really have no idea what I'm doing here. Any help will be welcomed, and greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and how exactly didn't it work?

Comment: The link you mention is pretty spot on. I have used it a few times recently and I'm working great.

Answer (score 2):

For sprite sheet animation you have to make a plist for all your images.

Download texture packer : https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

After installing the texture packer, add sprites to it and publish it.

It will create a plist.
Add that plist and png to the resources folder of your project.

Now add the following code to the init() of your GameLayer :

```
SpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("BowArrow.plist");
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
     frame = String::createWithFormat("Bow%d.png", i);
     frames.pushBack(
     SpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(
     frame->getCString()));
 }
```

Now you have all the sprites of plist in a framecache and you can run animation on them in the way you want.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make animations using **GIF**, i made so in my game and never had performance issues, you can make a GIF from web GIF Maker